# Is it possible to use newer bundle version than specified in manifest without altering current bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

Is it possible to use newer bundle version than specified in manifest without altering current bundle?

E.g. there are BundleA (my project) that require BundleB. BundleB requore import BundleC version [1.0.0,1.1.0). And this BundleB and BundleC are developed by third parties. Is there way to use BundleC version 1.5 without altering jar of BundleB?

Interface is same, just few important bugs were fixed in BundleC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since it would violate the version constraint expressed by BundleB.

Comment: Also... why was BundleC's version number bumped from 1.1 up to 1.5 when all you/they did was fix some bugs? Please read the Semantic Versioning whitepaper: http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/Links/SemanticVersioning.pdf